# Redirect from https://a.site.com to https://a.site.com/sub

Tags: 2013, iis, redirect

I have a root site collection at https://a.site.com

Underneath this root site collection I have another site collection (host named) at https://a.site.com/sub

My users are interested in the site at https://a.site.com/sub and they have access to it. They do not have access to the root site collection at https://a.site.com.

The URL I want to tell them to use is https://a.site.com

**Is it possible to set up a redirect so when they put https://a.site.com into their browsers they are taken to https://a.site.com/sub?**

I have tried to use HTTP Redirect in IIS but have not been able to make it work correctly. The browser will throw "too many redirect" errors or the web server will show an error about the directory not existing.

Comment: Use a simple JavaScript redirect?

Comment: if you redirect from root site to 2nd level site collection, it will fix /sub issue but what will be the root level site collection, if user really want to access the root level then? it will always redirected to 2nd level

Comment: Akhoy - not an option as users do not have access to the root site collection
Waqas - I don't care about the root site, there is nothing there. It's actually the root site for the web application.

Comment: then why not move them to root level site collection?

Comment: Move what, the site at /sub? Or user permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking following options. As your Site collection is HSNC base.

1. why not create another url, Lets say b.site.com and set that to your /sub site collection.
2. Move the /Sub site collection to root level using backup and restore.
3. lastly you can think about the Vanity URL and configured it to your IIS.check [this](http://Redirection%20options%20in%20SharePoint) or [this](http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2014/03/url-redirection-vanity-url-in-iis-75.html#.VuGCL_krKCg)

Comment: It was your second suggestion that I went with in the end. But I did not use backup/restore. I used export/import.